# Should I create Android Activity for each Imageview?

Tags: android, image, android-activity

I have to create an android app based on images where I have to show 100+ images. So my question is should I need to create each activity for showing only one image per activity or there is some other way to handle project like this, if yes then how?

Comment: If you want something like a slideshow, where you can scroll through the images you should consider using `ViewPager` . There are many tutorials available for it. Here is the link to official android developer documentation http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't.

If I understood you correctly, what you need is for example a 
[ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html)

There are other possibilities offcourse, but that depends on your specific needs, regarding your design etc.

Comment: Hi Udi, I don't know what to do with ViewFlipper, please if you have ready made coding of project like this, then please share with me thanks..

Comment: Just google it, there a lot of examples.

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/viewflipper/android-viewflipper-example/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you can use a single image view and dynamically change the image inside.

Do not create an activity per image!

Comment: Yeah I want to dynamically change in the image inside when user click or swipe screen its change image also.. But Q is how to do it ?